# What about this combination of と and や

Tags: grammar

For Full context, see here:
https://www.docdroid.net/5vuuiCe/img-20170821-0002-new.pdf

The problem is in this sentence (line 1):

> 「"KARAOKE"は、今では "JUDO" や "TSUNAMI"　と並ぶ世界共通語になっている。」

Here's my attempt at translation:
"'Karaoke' nowadays is becoming lined up common world language with 'Judo' and 'Tsunami'etc. ."

並ぶ seems to be an attribute to 世界共通語. That's why I think of it as [**X** = subject] [**is becoming** = predicative] [**lined up common world language** = object/copula-object or what it is called in english terminology].
This makes little sense in my opinion, but I can't see another way of linking these elements.

Then there is the thing with と and や. や marks an unfinished list/enumeration. The enumeration can't end with と, since this marks a finished list. と as a marker for quotation doesn't really work here as well, same goes for conditional phrase particle. 
The only way I can think of is that と marks the relation between KARAOKE and "the unfinished list". So "Karaoke is becoming...**with** 1,2 etc."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "KARAOKE" は、今では "JUDO" や "TSUNAMI" と並ぶ世界共通語になっている。
>   *Karaoke*, along with *judo* and *tsunami*, has now become an international common word.

This 並ぶ is *to rank with*, *to rival* or *to match*. This と is not quotative, but a particle that can often correspond to English *with*. Practically, you need to remember which verb takes と. Here are some verbs that take non-quotative と:

- 彼と別れる to part *with* him
- 英語と比べる to compare *with* English
- 敵と戦う to fight *with* enemies
- 高さで富士山と並ぶ to rank *with* Mt. Fuji in height
- 日本語と異なる to differ *from* Japanese

This ている is not the progressive form, but it refers to a "continuation of state". See: [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)