# Understanding「実母なんて10人も兄弟いるのに、誰一人と仲良くないし、誰の連絡先も知らないよ。」

Tags: grammar, translation, particles

I am trying to understand

> 実母なんて10人も兄弟いるのに、誰一人と仲良くないし、誰の連絡先も知らないよ。

and have broken it into pieces:

> 実母なんて**10人も**兄弟いるのに

1. Which reading of 人 is here being used? Is 人 here being used as a counter?
2. Are there any implicit particles being dropped after 10人 or 兄弟?

> 誰一人**と**仲良くない**し**

3. Is し being used here as a conjunctive?
4. Why is と being used after 誰一人?
5. Is a good translation of this clause something like: "there doesn't exist a single friendly person"?

> **誰の連絡先も**知らないよ

6. Is there an implicit を particle being dropped here after 誰の連絡先 (since there is a も), since 知らない is a transitive verb and 誰の連絡先 is the direct object of this?

Comment: Isn't there も after 誰一人と?

Comment: 仲（が）いい means 'close [to someone]', not 'friendly'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. にん. It's a counter. も indicates 10 is a big number ("as many as 10").
2. Nothing is omitted after 10人 (も is explicitly there). が is omitted after 兄弟.
3. Yes, it's basically "and", but has a nuance of "moreoever" or "what's worse/more".
4. This と after 誰一人 is "with". AはBと仲が良い means "A is in good terms with B" or "A gets along with B". I believe も is missing after 誰一人と.
5. A literal translation would be "(my true mother) is not in good terms with anyone".
6. Yes, `(interrogative +) も (+ ～ない)` works by replacing を and が, but it doesn't replace other particles like と, に, へ and から. Compare:

   - 何も買わない。
     I'll buy nothing.
     <sub>(も has replaced を)</sub>
   - どこへも行かない。
     I'll go nowhere.
     <sub>(も follows へ)</sub>

> 実母なんて10人も兄弟(が)いるのに、誰一人とも仲良くないし、誰の連絡先も知らないよ。
> My (real) mother has (as many as) 10 siblings, but she gets along with no one (of them) and (what's worse) knows the contact information of no one.

Comment: Is なんてin this case equivalent to 「何と言う」, or is it being used in its 等 + とて  sense?

Comment: @George No, this なんて is just a nuanced topic marker. It's closer to など described [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97375/5010). This なんて adds a nuance like "hey my mom is worse!".

Comment: In more idiomatic English: "My real mother has all of 10 siblings, but doesn't get along with any of them, and doesn't even have any of their contact information."